# What is the best way to find min/max value in OpenGL ES Texture

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a 2D texture, I want to find the position (x,y) of min value inside this texture, any idea?

Platform: OpenGL ES 2.0 Android.

Note: OpenGL ES2.0 doesn't support mipmap rendering.

Comment: [Copy the texture data to CPU memory](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml) and iterate over all pixels to find the minimum. You can split the image into several blocks and process them in different threads to enhance performance on multi-core CPUs.

Comment: Well, which is it?  OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: @NicoSchertler: This day in age, I would hesitate to do any image processing by offloading it to the CPU. This is a very easy task to do on any D3D9-class hardware with fragment shader capabilities, if you properly structure the data (e.g. min/max texture).

Comment: @NicoSchertler  but if the texture is big, the transfer from GPU to CPU takes long time!!

Comment: @genpfault OpenGL ES2.0, so it doesn't support mipmap

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider exploiting the hierarchical nature of mipmap LODs and write the minimum value for a large cluster of points into lower LODs. You could work your way up the mip-chain to find the exact lowest value (and location) this way; by extension, if you use a two-channel texture you could write the maximum value too and use this for max determination as well... You would of course increase memory requirements, but the operation of min/max location would be extremely quick by comparison.

This technique is literally known as a min/max texture. It has many uses, though it is most often used in the context of shadows. Rather than doing a search that would take `O (n)` time, you can structure your texture into a tree-like structure using mipmaps and do the same thing in `O (log n)` time on the GPU. You do have to spend additional processing generating the min/max LODs, but this is a one-time operation.

The [following link](http://levelofdetail.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/lets-have-a-minmax-party/) provides quite a bit more detail on min/max textures, and I am sure you can find many more on Google...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the platform is OpenGL ES2.0 on Android, so it doesn't support mipmap LODs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593171/shader-is-not-running-if-i-bind-framebuffer-to-mipmap-texture/18754670#18754670

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily have to use mipmaps for this. Mipmaps are just a handy way of incorporating the general data structure into a single texture. You can accomplish the same thing by computing your texture coordinates per-LOD (this is your best bet) or using separate texture objects. The primary thing to takeaway here is that you need to use a data structure that accelerates the process, and in fragment shaders on GLES2.0 class hardware any data structure is going to have to be implemented relative to textures; you then have to modify algorithms to work with things like texture coords.

Comment: Just about everything from general data structures, all the way down to linked lists (dependent texture lookups), can be implemented using textures. You just have to be clever :)